# Casper.wait does not wait as expected

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to use the following program to wait for 5 seconds before clicking on the next link.. but I see `casper.wait` does not wait for 5 seconds at all.

I need to wait for 5 seconds so that ajax code on the url I want to scrape has enough time loading.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ['includes/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'],
        logLevel: "debug",              // Only "info" level messages will be logged
        verbose: true});
/*
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo(msg);
})
*/
//var page = require('webpage').create();

require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);

var fs=require('fs');
var system=require('system');

var pagenum =0;
var url = casper.cli.args[0];
//var xmlhttp;

function getPageContent() 
{   
    var checkNext = true;
    while(checkNext==true)
    {
        casper.wait(5000);
        console.log("wait done");
        casper.echo(checkNext);
        content = casper.getHTML();
        fs.write("caspertest1.html", content, 'a');

        var nextLink = system.stdin.readLine();

        var checkNext = casper.evaluate(function(nextLink) 
        {
            //arb = ($(nextLink).is(":disabled"));
            //addRequestCallback(function(xhr) {
            //console.log("request",xhr);
            //});
        arb = ($(nextLink).is(":not([disabled])"));

                //arb = $(nextLink);
                console.log(arb);   
                //arb0 = arb[0];
                //console.log(arb0);
                //arbnew = $(arb0).is(":not([disabled])");
                console.log(nextLink);
                //arb = ($(nextLink).text());
                //$.on('ajaxComplete ready',lamba);

                return arb;
                //return arbnew;
            },nextLink);

        pagenum = pagenum+1;
        casper.echo("scraped page "+pagenum);
        casper.echo("clicking next link");
        casper.click(nextLink);
    }
}
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0');

casper.start(url);

casper.then(getPageContent);

console.log("about to run");

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `casper.then*` and `casper.wait*` functions are asynchronous. If you call them, their actions are scheduled at the end of the current step. This means that calling synchronous functions like `console.log`, `casper.echo` and `casper.evaluate` after `casper.wait` will result in their immediate execution and the `wait` will be scheduled for later.

You need to add the synchronous functions into the `then` callback of `wait`:

```
casper.wait(5000, function(){
    console.log("wait done");
    casper.echo(checkNext);
    content = casper.getHTML();
    fs.write("caspertest1.html", content, 'a');
    // and so on
});
```

But since the execution is asynchronous now, you cannot use a loop which depends on the state of a variable which is set asynchronously. You need to do this recursively:

```
var checkNext = true;
function getPageContent() 
{
    if (!checkNext) { return; }
    casper.wait(5000, function(){
        console.log("wait done");
        casper.echo(checkNext);
        content = casper.getHTML();
        fs.write("caspertest1.html", content, 'a');

        var nextLink = system.stdin.readLine();

        checkNext = casper.evaluate(function(nextLink) 
        {
            arb = ($(nextLink).is(":not([disabled])"));
                console.log(arb);   
                console.log(nextLink);
                return arb;
        },nextLink);

        pagenum = pagenum+1;
        casper.echo("scraped page "+pagenum);
        casper.echo("clicking next link");
        casper.click(nextLink);
    });
    casper.then(getPageContent);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way i can wait for AJAX to load instead of hardcoding them to 5s. I tried waitfor method of casperjs but it will not work because i dont know what will be the selector i will be waiting for. I just need the whole Ajax to be loaded on the page before dumping HTML. Any thoughts ? I appreciate your help

Comment: If you don't know the selector, then no. There are some [tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26848622) that you can try.