# Waiting for a page to load in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

In my test, I need to wait for a page to load before proceeding.  `waitForSelector` and `waitForText` aren't working for some reason, and while I can just use a `wait(value)`, I'd have to account for times the server might be slow and make the value a lot larger than I'd like; so I was thinking of making a while loop telling the system to wait 500 milliseconds every time it returns that 'someCSSpath' doesn't exist on the page.  Is there any way to do this (maybe a "casper.DoesntExist'?), or any better way to do it?

```
var css3path = "body > div.container-fluid > div:nth-child(3) > div.row.ng-scope > div:nth-child(1) > a > div";
casper.waitForSelector(css3path , function(){
    this.test.assertExists(css3path ); 
    if (casper.exists(css3path ){
        this.echo("logged in!");}
    else{
        this.echo("not logged in");
    };
});
```

When I use a `casper.wait(6000, function(){`
instead of `waitForSelector`, it works fine.
I use waitforselector earlier with the same format, and that works too; I think it's the specific thing I'm looking for that's giving me trouble.

Also, when I use `wait(6000,` the test finds that CSS3 path just fine; it's just `waitForSelector` that can't find it.

Comment: That's exactly what `waitForSelector()`. You probably aren't using it right. Please show your code, what you expect to happen and what actually happens (including error messages, screenshot descriptions). To be on the safe side: Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS selector exists. Maybe you're checking a desktop based CSS selector, but PhantomJS loads the mobile site that doesn't have such a selector.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? In v1.x there is a bug with :nth-child selectors

Comment: I use 1.9.2 I think?
yup, 1.9.2.  Is that what the problem is?  I read somewhere that for casper I needed a version pre-2

Comment: should I download a more recent version, or try to find another way to get the test to move as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: You could try to use XPath selectors like this: `var x = require('casper').selectXPath; casper.waitForSelector(x("//body/div[contains(@class,'container-fluid')]/div[3]/div[contains(@class,'row') and contains(@class,'ng-scope')]/div[1]/a/div"), function(){...`; Have you printed the page source after using `wait(time)` and looked whether the element actually exists?

Comment: Could I use inspect element and copy xpath in my browser, and would the code in casper look like casper.waitForSelector(x("copiedxpath"), function(){...?  Also, while I haven't printed the page source specifically, the test after the wait(time) found the element in question.

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: It didn't work.  It just kept on waiting, even past 20 seconds (the timeout I set).  Oh well, six seconds wait isn't so bad.  I'll just leave it as wait(6000).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163583/how-to-wait-for-page-loading-when-using-casperjs/45114053#45114053 See my comment.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know why exactly `waitForSelector` and `waitForText` aren't working. Are they timing out? Are they not finding the required selector or text?

If they are timing out, what I would recommend is changing the default amount of time Casper will wait for until it sends a time-out message. You change this using `casper.options` before you begin your tests like so:

```
//Set time-out to 20000 milliseconds (20 seconds)
casper.options.waitTimeout = 20000;

casper.test.begin('Begin tests', function suite(test)
{
    //Your tests go here
}
```

It's important to have a time-out rather than a while loop that may loop definitely. If there's something wrong with the server then the tests will time-out and you will know something is wrong.

Check out this question for more info on Javascript while loops to wait for a flag:

[Javascript - wait until flag=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125865/javascript-wait-until-flag-true)

Comment: It used to time out, but for some reason it's not doing that anymore, it's just sitting there, waiting I suppose.

Comment: The default amount of time until time out is 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds), so that might explain why your `casper.wait(6000, function()` worked (it may take more than 5 seconds but less than 6 to load). Other than that, I'm afraid I can't offer more advice until you do what Artjom B. suggested. Any more context and/or error messages would be very helpful

Comment: Out of interest, what is the entire CSS3 path that you're using? @2manysemicolons

Comment: body > div.container-fluid > div:nth-child(3) > div.row.ng-scope > div:nth-child(1) > a > div

Comment: also, the time it takes varies from 3-6 seconds.  Waitforselector never finds it.

Comment: This may be a longshot, but try `nth-of-type(n)`. I had a similar problem of not being able to interact with selectors that used `nth-child(n)`, even though they passed `exists` tests

Comment: I'd say change it in the part of the code in your answer and see if it works first before you change large amounts of code, like I said, it's just a longshot